# Underline movement on clicking next button in tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need a an underline when the next button is clicked on the heading of the tab. If we click the tab the underline works properly but if we hit next button it stays on about tab and does not move to next tab. please help me to move the underline to the next tab. Thanks in advance

Here is my code of the tab that displays the content.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
 body {font-family: Arial;}

  /* Style the tab */
.tab {
 overflow: hidden;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 background-color: #f1f1f1;
  }

  /* Style the buttons inside the tab */
  .tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
 transition: 0.3s;
 font-size: 17px;
  }

  /* Change background color of buttons on hover */
  .tab button:hover {

  }

  /* Create an active/current tablink class */
 .tab button.active {
 text-decoration: underline;
 text-decoration-thickness: 2px;
 text-decoration-color: #6A72EA;
 padding-bottom:2px;
 display:inline-block;
  }


  /* Style the tab content */
  .tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
 border-top: none;
  }

 #con {
 width: 370px;
 margin: auto;

      }
   .bgc{
   background-color: #6A72EA;
   color: white;
   text-align:center;
   margin-bottom: -16px;
   padding: 10px;
   border-radius:15px;
   }
   </style>
   </head>
   <body>

  <h2>Tabs</h2>
  <p>Click on the buttons inside the tabbed menu:</p>
  <div id = "con" >
  <div class="bgc">
  <p>
      Let's create you personal nutritional profile to determine your Macros & keep track of how much you should eat,which helps you to achieve your body goals!
    </p>
   </div>
   <div class="tab">
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'About')">About</button>
   <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Activity level')">Activity level</button>
   <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Goals')">Goals</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Result')">Result</button>
    </div>

  <div id="About" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>About</h3>
  <p>Say some thing about yourself.</p>


    </div>

   <div id="Activity level" class="tabcontent">
   <h3>Activity level</h3>
   <p>How active are you?</p>
   </div>

   <div id="Goals" class="tabcontent">
   <h3>Goals</h3>
   <p>What is your goal</p>
   </div>
   <div id="Result" class="tabcontent">
   <h3>Result</h3>
   <p>This is the  New Result.</p>
  </div>
  </div>
 <script>
 function openTab(evt, tabName) {
 var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
 tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
  tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
   }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
  tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
   document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
    }
   </script>

  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Being not to sure is fine, but please try it and then come here with your best attempt.

Comment: What I understood from your question is when someone clicks on about the tab button, its content ope along with the activity button show in this tab. The same thing happens when the activity button gets clicked, goals button appear along with the content of the activity. Is this correct?

Comment: @pranay I wanted a next button in tab content to go to next tab and paras has guided me very well. I inserted the next button in all the three tab except result now I want to underline the tab heading, when we go to activity tab by pressing next button there should be underline on activity. how to do that

Comment: now i am change and add underline please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this**

```
  <html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {font-family: Arial;}

/* Style the tab */
 .tab {
  overflow: hidden;
   border: 1px solid #ccc;
   background-color: #f1f1f1;
     }

   /* Style the buttons inside the tab */
  .tab button {
   background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
  }

 /* Change background color of buttons on hover */
 .tab button:hover {

 }

  /* Create an active/current tablink class */
 .tab button.active {
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration-thickness: 2px;
  text-decoration-color: #6A72EA;
  padding-bottom:2px;
  display:inline-block;
  }


 /* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
  display: none;
 padding: 6px 12px;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 border-top: none;
 }

 #con {
 width: 370px;
 margin: auto;

  }
 .bgc{
 background-color: #6A72EA;
 color: white;
 text-align:center;
 margin-bottom: -16px;
 padding: 10px;
 border-radius:15px;
   }
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>

 <h2>Tabs</h2>
 <p>Click on the buttons inside the tabbed menu:</p>
 <div id = "con" >
 <div class="bgc">
 <p>
   Let's create you personal nutritional profile to determine your Macros & keep track of how much you should eat,which helps you to achieve your body goals!
 </p>
  </div>
 <div class="tab">
 <button class="tablinks About" onclick="openTab(event, 'About')">About</button>
 <button class="tablinks Activity" onclick="openTab(event, 'Activity level')">Activity level</button>
 <button class="tablinks Goals" onclick="openTab(event, 'Goals')">Goals</button>
 <button class="tablinks Result" onclick="openTab(event, 'Result')">Result</button>
 </div>

<div id="About" class="tabcontent">
<h3>About</h3>
<p>Say some thing about yourself.</p>


</div>

 <div id="Activity" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Activity level</h3>
  <p>How active are you?</p>
  </div>

  <div id="Goals" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Goals</h3>
  <p>What is your goal</p>
  </div>
<div id="Result" class="tabcontent">
<h3>Result</h3>
<p>This is the  New Result.</p>
</div>
</div>
<button id="next" onclick="nextTab()">Next</button>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function nextTab(){
    $('button.tablinks').removeClass('active');
    var id=$('.tabcontent:visible').attr('id');
    if(id){
       $('.tabcontent:visible').next('.tabcontent').show();
      $('#'+id).hide();
      id=$('.tabcontent:visible').attr('id');
      $('button.tablinks.'+id).addClass('active');
    }else{
      $('#About').show();
       $('button.tablinks.about').addClass('active');
    }



  }
function openTab(evt, tabName) {
var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
 for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
  tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
   }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
  tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
   }
   document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "block";
   evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
   }
  </script>

  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: 90% is completed only the underline when it is on goal is should underline goal ans same thing in all can you help in that

Comment: very much thank you can we chat in private please I need some more help

Comment: Please put here your all question

Answer (score 0):

I added underlines.

```html
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />


    <style>
        body {
            font-family: Arial;
        }

        /* Style the tab */

        .tab {
            overflow: hidden;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            background-color: #f1f1f1;
        }

        /* Style the buttons inside the tab */

        .tab button {
            background-color: inherit;
            float: left;
            border: none;
            outline: none;
            cursor: pointer;
            padding: 14px 16px;
            transition: 0.3s;
            font-size: 17px;
        }

        /* Change background color of buttons on hover */

        .tab button:hover {}

        /* Create an active/current tablink class */

        .tab button.active {
            text-decoration: underline;
            text-decoration-thickness: 2px;
            text-decoration-color: #6A72EA;
            padding-bottom: 2px;
            display: inline-block;
        }


        /* Style the tab content */

        .tabcontent {
            display: none;
            padding: 6px 12px;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-top: none;
        }

        #con {
            width: 370px;
            margin: auto;

        }

        .bgc {
            background-color: #6A72EA;
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
            margin-bottom: -16px;
            padding: 10px;
            border-radius: 15px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <h2>Tabs</h2>
    <p>Click on the buttons inside the tabbed menu:</p>
 
   <button class="bgc" id="next" onclick="nextTab()">Next</button>
   
   
    <div id="con">
        <div class="bgc">
            <p>
                Let's create you personal nutritional profile to determine your Macros & keep track of how much you should eat,which helps
                you to achieve your body goals!
            </p>
   
     
    
    
        </div>
        <div class="tab">
            <button class="tablinks" data-target="About" id="buttonAbout">About</button>
            <button class="tablinks" data-target="Activity" id="buttonActivity">Activity level</button>
            <button class="tablinks" data-target="Goals" id="buttonGoals">Goals</button>
            <button class="tablinks" data-target="Result" id="buttonResult">Result</button>
        </div>

        <div id="About" data-target="buttonAbout" class="tabcontent tabcontent-about">
            <h3>About</h3>
            <p>Say some thing about yourself.</p>


        </div>

        <div id="Activity" data-target="buttonActivity" class="tabcontent tabcontent-activity">
            <h3>Activity level</h3>
            <p>How active are you?</p>
        </div>

        <div id="Goals" data-target="buttonGoals" class="tabcontent tabcontent-goals">
            <h3>Goals</h3>
            <p>What is your goal</p>
        </div>
        <div id="Result" data-target="buttonResult" class="tabcontent tabcontent-result">
            <h3>Result</h3>
            <p>This is the New Result.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var activeTopic = "buttonAbout";


        function nextTab() {
            var id = $('.tabcontent:visible').attr('id');
            if (id) {

                $('.tabcontent:visible').next('.tabcontent').show();
                activeTopic = $("#" + id).next('.tabcontent').attr("data-target");
                let currentBox = document.getElementById(id);
                var button = $("#" + id).next('.tablinks').attr("id");
                $(".tablinks").removeClass("active");
                $("#" + activeTopic).addClass("active");
                $('#' + id).hide();
            } else {
                $(".tablinks").removeClass("active");
                $("#buttonAbout").addClass("active");
                $('#About').show();
            }
        }

        $(".tablinks").on("click", function (event) {
            var target = $(this).attr("data-target");
            activeTopic = target;
            console.log(activeTopic);
            $(".tablinks").removeClass("active");
            $(this).addClass("active");
            $(".tabcontent").hide();
            $("#" + target).show();
            $("#" + target).addClass("active");
        });
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```